# Twitter Bootstrap - Open one menu, automatically closes another

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, drop-down-menu

Okay, so first of all, here's my site: http://songfreek.com

Upon the site loading, the "User" menu is opened, and the rest are closed. Now, when I open another menu (lets say the "Radio DJ" tab), both the "User" menu and "Radio DJ" menu are opened.

I'd like to make it so if I clicked the "Radio DJ" menu, then the "User" menu would close, and so on.

Here's my code from the "User" menu to "Radio DJ" menu.

```
                        <!-- USER -->
                        <li class="nav-header">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#userMenu">
                                <font color="#333333">User</font> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul style="list-style: none;" class="collapse in" id="userMenu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> Messages <span class="badge badge-info">4</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cogs"></i> Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-comment"></i> Shoutbox</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Staff List</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-flag"></i> My Infractions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> Rules &amp; Regulations</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <!-- RADIO DJ -->
                        <li class="nav-header">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#radioDJMenu">
                                <font color="#34CCFF">Radio DJ</font> <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul style="list-style: none;" class="collapse" id="radioDJMenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Information &amp; Stats</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">DJ Says</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Request Line</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Banned Songs</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, lets go 3 for 3 on songfreek.com...

You can close any other open menus by assigning a function to the `collapse` 'show' event like this:

```
    $('.collapse').on('show', function (e) {

        // hide open menus
        $('.collapse').each(function(){
          if ($(this).hasClass('in')) {
              $(this).collapse('toggle');
          }
        });
    })
```

When any menu is open, the 'show' event is triggered. Any other menus that are open will contain the `in` class so `collapse('toggle')` can be used to close them.

I've updated the Bootply at **http://bootply.com/61710** to demonstrate this.

Comment: I'm still having problems with this. Could you help me out somehow? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.